# Creating dynamic popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

**js**

```
 $(function () {
     var dmJSON = "clues.json";
     $.getJSON(dmJSON, function (data) {
         var idx = 1;
         $.each(data.details, function (i, f) {
             var myid = 'mypop' + String(idx);
             idx++;
             var $popup = "<popup id='" + myid + "' class='mystyles1'><tr>" + "<p>" + f.Myclue + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + f.Description + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + f.Updates + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p> " + f.Users + "</p></tr>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</popup>"
             $("#popup-container").append($popup)

         });

     });
 });
```

I want to create dynamic popup and display data from json file onclick of a dynamic table. With the above code the popup displays the entire json data whereas i want particular data to be displayed. Any solution to this would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: _"i want particular data to be displayed."_ What is particular data to be displayed ?

Comment: {
"details": [
  {
    "Myclue" : "First Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the first clue",
    "Updates" : "Rejected",
    "Users" : "10"
  },
  {
    "Myclue" : "Second Clue",
    "Description" : "Answer to the second clue",
    "Updates" : "Amazing",
    "Users" : "15"
  },

Comment: From the json file i want the first clue details to display in one pop up then the second clue details displayed in another popup because they belong to different tables

Comment: What is not occurring according to expected results ? Can reproduce at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319215/create-dynamic-popup-window?noredirect=1#comment48733570_30319215  This is my actual question

Comment: _"Please check this link"_ ? No link appear at comment ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319215/create-dynamic-popup-window ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
$(function () {
     var dmJSON = "clues.json";
     $.getJSON(dmJSON, function (data) {
         var idx = 1;
     for (var i =0; i < data.details.length; i++) {
         var myid = 'mypop' + String(idx);
         idx++;
         var $popup += "<popup id='" + myid + "' class='mystyles1'><tr>" + "<p>" + data.details[i].Myclue + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + data.details[i].Description + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p>" + data.details[i].Updates + "</p></tr>" + "<tr><p> " + data.details[i].Users + "</p></tr>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</popup>"

     }
     $("#popup-container").append($popup);

     });
 });
```

Comment: I used this code. The popup should appear onclick of a table. When i used   for loop, tables are not displayed

Comment: Should i use the table id ?

Comment: Yeah append the html to a table

Comment: you mean instead of .append($popup); i should use .append($table); in this code

Comment: No, you need to insert the rows into a table for them to display. Does your table have an id of #popup-container? I'm assuming it doesn't, so you need to do something like this:
HTML:
<div id="popup-container"><table></table></div>
JS
$("#popup-container table").html($popup);